# Mirror mathcal letter

Tags: symbols, mathcal

Is there a way to mirror a symbol like `\mathcal{P}`, but keep it cursive in the right way? Using `\reflectbox{\mathcal{P}}` gives a mirrored version of `\mathcal{P}` that slopes in the wrong direction.

Comment: Is there a reason you need this, other than intellectual curiosity and/or fun? I'm unsure whether I'd consider a math article with mirrored mathcal symbols to have good notation. :p

Comment: I thought it would be fun to use for the contravariant powerset functor, as it is the reverse of my covariant powerset functor. Not sure if I'd use it in a paper though :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This also uses pdf magic, set up in a systematic way.  Unfortunately, it seems each glyph needs its own custom kern.  However, when accounted for, the result does not suffer from falling outside of its boundary issues..

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools,scalerel}
\newsavebox{\foobox}
\newcommand{\slantbox}[2][.5]{\mbox{%
        \sbox{\foobox}{#2}%
        \hskip\wd\foobox
        \pdfsave
        \pdfsetmatrix{1 0 #1 1}%
        \llap{\usebox{\foobox}}%
        \pdfrestore
}}
\newcommand\rmathcal[2][0mu]{\ThisStyle{\reflectbox{\slantbox[-.55]{%
  $\SavedStyle\mathcal{\mkern#1#2\mkern-#1}$}}}}
\begin{document}
\fboxsep=1pt
\fbox{$\mathcal{P}\rmathcal[5mu]{P}\mathcal{P}$}

$\mathcal{Q}\rmathcal{Q}\mathcal{Q}$
\fbox{$\scriptstyle\mathcal{Q}\rmathcal{Q}\mathcal{Q}$}
$\scriptscriptstyle\mathcal{Q}\rmathcal{Q}\mathcal{Q}$

$\mathcal{Y}\rmathcal[4mu]{Y}\mathcal{Y}$
$\scriptstyle\mathcal{Y}\rmathcal[4mu]{Y}\mathcal{Y}$
\fbox{$\scriptscriptstyle\mathcal{Y}\rmathcal[4mu]{Y}\mathcal{Y}$}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 6):

You can pair `\mathpalette` with some PDF magic.  This will only work in pdfTeX.  It's not fine-tuned and I've only tested it somewhat for the letter `P`.  It doesn't look that great in subscripts and weird shit is happening when you use multiple letters, but you get the idea.

```
\documentclass{article}

\makeatletter

\DeclareRobustCommand\mathcalr[1]{%
    \mathpalette\@mathcalr{#1}%
}

\newcommand\@mathcalr[2]{%
    \mskip2mu
    \pdfsave
    \pdfsetmatrix{-1 0 .633 1}%
    \hb@xt@\z@{\hss$\m@th#1\mathcal{#2}$\hss}%
    \pdfrestore
    \mskip12mu
}

\makeatother

\begin{document}
\fbox{$b\mathcal{P}a$}

\fbox{$a\mathcalr{P}b$}

\fbox{$_{a\mathcalr{P}b}$}

\fbox{$_{_{a\mathcalr{P}b}}$}

\fbox{$\mathcalr{ABC}$} % oops
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 5):

With `unicode-math`, it is possible to make a math font slant left with a negative value of `FakeSlant=`, before reflecting it.  You will still need some manual kerning before and after the `\reflectbox`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{unicode-math}

\pagestyle{empty}

\setmathfontface{\mathleftslant}{Latin Modern Math}[FakeSlant=-0.6]
\newcommand\mirrorcalP{%
  \kern-0.25em%
  \reflectbox{%
  \(\mathleftslant{\mscrP}\)%
  }%
  \kern0.1em}

\begin{document}
\[ \mathcal{P}\mirrorcalP\mathcal{Q} \]
\end{document}
```

[image: Latin Modern Math sample]

While it would be possible to define a `\mirrorcal{P}` command, it would require individual fine-tuning for every symbol anyway, and you probably only need one or two of them.

You might, however, define `\mirrorcalP` as `\@mirrorsym{\mscrP}{-2.5em}{0.1em}` if you need to declare a large number of these.